# Javascript - Set the value of this

Tags: javascript

How do I set the value of `this` in Javascript?
For example:

```
var obj = {
    a: 'b',
    c: "d",
    e: function() {
        this = {
            one: 1,
            two: 2
        };
    }
};
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you're making the `{one:1,two:2}` object inside the function, why do you need to assign it to `this`? What are you actually trying to accomplish? See [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot explicitly assign the value of `this` in javascript like you are asking.

Once a function starts executing, the value of `this` inside that exact function will not change (though embedded functions can have their own value of `this`).

You can assign properties to `this` such as this so perhaps that's what you want:

```
this.one = 1;
this.two = 2;
```

---

Instead, `this` is controlled by the caller of a function and how the function is called is what determines what `this` is set to inside the function.  For example:

```
obj.e()
```

will set the value of `this` inside of `e()` to be `obj`.

---

You can also use `.apply()` and `.call()` to cause the value of `this` to be set to something other than the containing object.

For example to do what you asked, this code:

```
var test = {one:1, two:2};
var obj = { a:'b', c:"d", e:function(){
    // this will be set to the test object in here when called as below
}};

obj.e.call(test);
```

will cause the value of `this` inside of this specific call to `e()` to be set to your requested object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { a:'b', c:"d", e:function(){
  // Here, this.one === 1 and this.two === 2
}.bind({ one: 1, two : 2})};
```

Answer (score 0):

'this' is a reserved keyword that cannot be set inside a function body.

You can call a function with a specific value of this using `apply` or `call` methods on the function. `obj.e.call({one: 1, two: 2})`. Look up the MDN articles on those two Function methods.

You can also use ECMAScript 5's `bind` method to permanently set the value of `this` every time a function is called. That's an ECMAScript 5 method so doesn't work in old browsers, but there are polyfills you can use that add support for it to old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
this.one=1;
this.two=2;
```